# How to run a followup test after on PROCESS Macro Results in R?

Tags: r, interaction, mediation

Part of the attraction of the Hayes PROCESS Macro in R is that it will generate the index of moderated mediation. It tells you if your indirect effect varies by the level of a moderator variable.

I'm doing a moderated mediation analysis. BUT because I have a moderator variable with three categories, it actually generates two indices of moderated mediation (see output at the bottom).

I need a single up-or-down test. I know the solution ordinarily would be to just run a joint test on the null that both indices = 0. But is there a way to do this as a followup test with PROCESS? I've lookup up how to calculate this by hand, but PROCESS doesn't give you the SSR (sum of squared residuals) you'd need to do that.

```
     Indices of partial moderated mediation:
              Index    BootSE  BootLLCI  BootULCI
p_ment      -0.1135    0.0669   -0.2486    0.0168
p_read      -0.1845    0.0629   -0.3123   -0.0668
```

Comment: The PROCESS macro, created by Andrew Hayes, is one such instrument. The PROCESS macro essentially computes regression analyses involving different combinations of mediators, moderators, and variables through unapproved (but safe to use!) modifications to statistical software like SPSS.

Comment: If you are using R, it might make sense to use `lavaan` to perform the mediation analysis. You can fit a model with moderation and a model without and test whether one fits better than the other using a likelihood ratio test. Instructions for mediation in `lavaan` are [here](https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/mediation.html), but it might take a bit of work to make the moderation happen.